# How to I share project-specific settings from Eclipse to Intelij?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I know how to [migrate global settings](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/01/intellij-idea-13-importing-code-formatter-settings-from-eclipse/) from Eclipse to Intellij.

But I don't see a way to migrate project specific settings, stored in the project  `.settings` folder in `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs`  and `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`.

Example of values in these files include:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.codeComplete.staticFinalFieldSuffixes=
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.annotation.inheritNullAnnotations=disabled
....
cleanup.convert_to_enhanced_for_loop=false
cleanup.correct_indentation=true
```

How do I migrate these?

Comment: Have you tried [Eclipse Code Formatter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546-eclipse-code-formatter) plugin?

Comment: Thank you, I tried that now, and that might do it.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support import of such settings, however, you may try using custom plugins.

Comment: What plugin, for example?

Comment: Unfortunately there are no JetBrains plugins for it. I know custom one, Eclipse Code Formatter, that Andey already mentioned.